# TFS 2017 Page loading issues for static icons and images

Tags: team-foundation-server

I've been working on a project whereby we are working to split the web tier onto a separate server from the app tier per our security requirements. It's actually worked really well with the exception of one piece. When accessing the TFS site everything loads except the static page bits (some fonts, banner images and icons). I've confirmed through logs on the app server that the service account appears to be granted access to the files but they are not actually rendered on the page. Furthermore, for each of these items that is attempting to load a login prompt appears and user credentials do not appear to work when entered. The problem mostly only occurs when HTTPS only is enforced. If I leave 8080/HTTP as the primary URL and don't enforce SSL it seems to work better because there are no longer continuous login prompts but some icons are still missing. Looking at the page inspection when loading the SSL enforced page the content failing to load shows HTTP/1.0 with a 401 error but it's URL referenced has HTTPS listed. When using the direct HTTPS URL for the icon or image file it will download fine. Then since the file is cached I can refresh the TFS page and that icon/image will load properly without logon prompt, until I clear browser cache. 
 I feel like this is something misbehaving within TFS.  I have group policies configured correctly for the service account with impersonating of logons and logon as a service set on both web and app tier servers so I don't believe that is the issue.  I've tried this on a few different builds of 2017 all with similar results.  Currently on 2017 Update 3.1 patch 6 and TFS is configured to use Negotiate since we have NTLM restrictions in the environment.

**UPDATE:**
Wanted to get back on here and explain in further detail but I've been busy. We follow NIST 800-53 requirements and adhere to CIS Level 2.  As such the recommended configuration for a web application is to be three-tier (web, app, and data).  TFS by default will technically allow up to 2 tiers where the app and web are on the same box.  I need to move the web to a different box for true three-tier architecture.  So I think I've managed to figure out a way to sort of 'trick' TFS into thinking there's a third server for the web that isn't actually using the app services like the app tier does and essentially separating the two tiers as result.

This is how I achieved where I am currently.  These are all Server 2016 boxes.

1. Deploy SQL 2016 box and added the service account to SQL with
   sysadmin ahead of the TFS install
2. Stand up the web server and app server.  Added the service account to both “Impersonate a client after authentication” and
   “logon as a service” policies on both systems.
3. Install TFS on the app server, pointing to the SQL box during configuration letting the install create the databases.  Setup with
   self-signed TFS issued cert initially to get it going and set HTTPS
   redirect as well so the web.config files are already preset for
   this.
4. Install TFS on the web server but do NOT configure any features.
5. On the TFS app export IIS app pools and sites using Command Prompt and copy to the web server.  Disable IIS services.  On the
   TFS install folder and TFSCache folder setup network shares and
   grant the tfsservice account read/write access and NETWORK SERVICE
   along with the TFS_Users group read access. (this part I’m still not
   100% sure on and have played with numerous variations with little
   change in results other than the TFS_Users group seems to be what
   allows me to pull down most of the static site bits)
6. On the web server, edit the exported ‘sites’ file to adjust the bindings to point to itself instead of the app server and update the
   physical paths for all three entries to their respective UNC path on
   the app server.  Import the app pools and sites.  In IIS update the
   bindings with an internal CA issued cert and Edit the Application
   Settings > dataDirectory to point to the UNC path of the tfs_cache. 
   Restart IIS.
7. Back on the app server open TFS admin console and update the public URL to point to the web  box.  Hit Test so it validates and
   accepts the cert.  (I also installed the cert on the app server just
   for good measure since I read something about a multi-server
   deployment with multiple app servers needs to have them all issued
   the correct cert when using SSL certs from a CA. Not sure if this
   was actually necessary or not for my configuration.)
8. Once updated, test access to TFS.

TFS will add the web box to the Application Servers list in the admin console but none of the features on the web box are configured.  TFS sees it almost as a TFS Proxy as it enables the TFS_Proxy local security group on the web box but does not actually create the TFS_Application_Tier security group like it does on the app server.  The web server also doesn’t function as your typical ‘TFS Proxy’ since it’s not caching data locally for use like it would if you setup the Proxy feature.

I think that’s the quick dirty run down but I’ll go back through my write-up I did while going through all this to keep track of what I was doing and make sure I didn’t miss anything pertinent.

Comment: Can you explain how "split the web tier onto a separate server from the app tier per our security requirements" relates to TFS? You mean that you are trying to put a (reverse) proxy like ngnix in front of TFS AppTier?

Comment: Updated the post with a bit more detail that hopefully helps see what I've been trying to accomplish.  I may be going down a wrong path for all I know too so that would be good to get an opinion on as well.

Comment: AFAIK what you are trying is undocumented and unsupported. In your shoes, I will use IIS + ARR or ngnix or HAproxy for the "Web" tier configured for SSL and Windows Authentication redirecting the traffic to a normally configured TFS AT. You can try open a ticket (SR) with Microsoft support but I won't put my bet on it.

Comment: Ya I know, I'm in uncharted territory for sure, which is what's making this tricky.  Sadly some A-hole who was using the SQL box for another app (it was a shared SQL box) caused a data breach with their app and the security team has confiscated the server so now I'm having to rebuild all this again.  But I had a different idea I think I'm going to try.  I'll let you know how it goes.